# What is the difference between t() and @Translation()?

Tags: i18n-l10n, 8

When writing a (translatable) plugin in Drupal 8, you have to `use Drupal\Core\Annotation\Translation;`, and then wrap your value in `@Translation("value")`, however when implementing the `FormInterface`, you can use `t()` freely as you would in Drupal 7.

I found [Annotation-based plugins](https://drupal.org/node/1882526) on Drupal.org, but it just mentions the fact that you should use it, and the [Doctrine reference](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/annotations-reference.html) doesn't seem to include `@Translation`

I assume it is because the plugin system is part of doctrine, and not part of core, whereas `t()` is  -is this the correct assumption?

Basically, what is the difference between `@Translation();` and `t()` - is it just because plugins are Doctrine based?

Comment: Isn't `@` in `@Translation("value")` just an [php error control operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php)? Just asking.

Comment: @Mołot Not :) _is it just because plugins are Doctrine based?_ not quite, it's because they're _annotation_ based. You can't call a PHP function from inside annotation metadata, so a special annotation has been defined to handle the same work that `t()` does. http://php-and-symfony.matthiasnoback.nl/2011/12/symfony2-doctrine-common-creating-powerful-annotations/ might be interesting reading as a grounding in custom annotations. I don't know the technical terms for these concepts inside Drupal so I won't put an answer in

Comment: @Clive so the basic difference is that `t()` is a PHP function, and `@Translation()` is not? Neat ;)

Comment: @Mołot I think the simplest way to put it is that `@Translation` is a wrapper around `t()`, only _practically_ accessible for use in the context of an annotation. The `Translation` plugin actually uses `t()` internally anyway. Chapabu, check out the comments in [`Drupal\Core\Annotation\Translation`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Annotation!Translation.php/8) and [`Drupal\Core\Annotation\Plugin`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Component%21Annotation%21Plugin.php/class/Plugin/8), they should go some way towards explaining this stuff :)

Comment: Best advice I can give for understanding how this stuff works is actually to build a custom entity/custom field/entity reference extension/views extension/etc. for Drupal 8. It all falls into place very quickly

Comment: @Clive Awesome. I've just grokked the routing, `FormInterface` and `SystemConfigFormBase` (and `ConfigFactory` stuff) so custom entities/fields was my next port of call anyway :)

Comment: Aport from actually translating it (that would also be possible by simply defining which keys for each plugin should be translated), an important aspect of it is that translatable strings can be extracted just like they can for t() using potx.module.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In short, `@Translation()` is a string used in annotations, meta data written in PHP comments and pertinent to a Drupal 8 class.

For example, this is the annotation for the [PathItem](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21path%21lib%21Drupal%21path%21Plugin%21DataType%21PathItem.php/class/PathItem/8) entity field class.

```
/**
 * Defines the 'path_field' entity field item.
 *
 * @DataType(
 *   id = "path_field",
 *   label = @Translation("Path field item"),
 *   description = @Translation("An entity field containing a path alias and related data."),
 *   list_class = "\Drupal\Core\Entity\Field\Field"
 * )
 */
```

When Drupal loads the class annotations from a file, and it finds `@Translation("Content")` in the annotation, it creates an instance of the [Translation](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Annotation!Translation.php/class/Translation/8) class whose constructor receives the `"Content"` string; the instance is then used to get the value of `t("Content")`.

As for the differences, they are the following ones:

- `@Translation()` is a **string** used in class annotations: plain text that follows a specific format and it is written in PHP comments before the class that is being annotated. You cannot use it in code similar to the following one, except in the case a module defines a `Translation()` function. In that case, the `@` before it would be understood from PHP as the [error control operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php).

  ```
  $form['salary'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => @Translation('Salary'),
    '#size' => 10,
    '#maxlength' => 10,
    '#description' => @Translation('Please enter a valid number'),
  );
  ```
- `t()` is a **Drupal function**. It cannot be used inside class annotations like the following one, since it doesn't follow the syntax annotations follow. If it were used in an annotation as in the following, it would not cause Drupal to call `t()` and use its return value.

  ```
  /**
   * Defines the 'path_field' entity field item.
   *
   * @DataType(
   *   id = "path_field",
   *   label = t("Path field item"),
   *   description = t("An entity field containing a path alias and related data."),
   *   list_class = "\Drupal\Core\Entity\Field\Field"
   * )
   */
  ```